# launching iOS bundle under root , jailbroken device

Tags: ios

I need to launch my application (GUI bundle app) with **root** privileges. The app access proprietary external hardware and needs to execute some code as **root**;  obviously device is jailbroken. I can do it via terminal or SSH but in that case applications behaves abnormally - I need to launch it as any other app by taping on springboard icon.

Comment: You might want to re-ask that here - http://security.stackexchange.com/  - in order to get more answers.